# Choosing a software licence

Tags: licensing

I want to release some javascript libraries under an open source license, but am having some difficulty picking one.  I want a license that meets the following requirements:

1. Credit must be given to the original author
2. Modification to the source code must be released open source
3. Software can be sold, modified, or bundled with propriety software.

Are there any open source licenses that fit this bill well?

I have considered the MPL but I don't know if it requires that credit be given to authors.

Comment: You should be more specific. If a propriety software use your lib, do you want to be sure that they will "credit" your lib ?

Comment: Yes, if the software is used, credit should be given.

Comment: What on earth does credit mean?  Their website will have to have a post on it listing the thank yous?  Photos the Mars robot takes will have to have "uses libraries powered by Daniel" watermarked?  Money? A thank you note with a gift card to Macy's?

Comment: I was envisioning something like a comment in the source code, or, if the source code is not distributed, a notice bundled somewhere with the software.  However, I am pretty flexible, I would just like a license that has some provision for attribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CC BY-SA seems to follow your "rules": http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

MPL seems ok too

Comment: Does MPL require credit be given?  If so, I will probably go with that one since I like what I have seen of it.

Comment: BY-SA is almost exactly what I am looking for, except that they recommend not using their licenses for software (shame too, they are easy to understand).  THus I would rather find a license designed for software.